# Loop through cells and import CSV files, by using the cells' value in the file path

Tags: excel, vba, loops, csv

I have 1 sheet with asset names in the top row and dates in the first column.

[image: Current file]

I need to loop trough all cells in the first row, take the cell's value and include it in the file path to import column 6 from a text file.

So far I've got this:

```
For i = 2 To HCP.Cells(1, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If HCP.Cells(1, i).Value <> "" Then
        j = HCP.Cells(2, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            With HCP.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Folder & "\" & i & "1440.CSV", Destination:=HCP.Cells(2, j + 1))
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                i = i + 1
            End With
    End If
Next
```

And I get this at the `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` line:

[image: Error Message]

I reckon I am not using the variables in the loop correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not actually setting i to any value in a cell, it's only your counter.  You need to set `HCP.Cells(1, i).Value` to a variable and pass that variable through your file path.

Try this:

```
For i = 2 To HCP.Cells(1, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    rowContent = HCP.Cells(1, i).Value

    If rowContent <> "" Then
        j = HCP.Cells(2, HCP.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            With HCP.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Folder & "\" & rowContent & "1440.CSV", Destination:=HCP.Cells(2, j + 1))
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

            End With
    End If
Next
```

Also you dont need `i = i + 1` in your code, the `Next` will automatically increment your i number up `To` the value you specified.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Senior Penguin. Unfortunately, with the code that you suggested I get some data imported before the same error occures, although the file(s) are in the folder.

Comment: You are getting a new error with the code or just the same error at the same spot?  One thing you can try is to set the whole file path as one variable like this: `filepath = Folder & "\" & rowContent & "1440.CSV"` Then step through the code with f8 and when you pass that line, hover your mouse over the `filepath` variable and make sure the text that appears matches your actual file path.